# Decreasing value in vectors with SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I created 5 numbers using vector with SFML, but I want the second one to fall one by one at intervals of 1 second. But, they first three falling as one by one. I don't understand why something like this is happening. Can you help me?

```
if (second == 1)
    {

    random.at(2)-=1;
    cout << random[2] << endl;
    text.setString(to_string(random[2]));
    text.setPosition(numbers[2].getPosition().x, numbers[2].getPosition().y);
    numbers.push_back(text);
    numbers.erase(numbers.begin() + 2);
    clock.restart();


}
```

[The program gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1RCZ.gif)

[Full code](https://pastebin.com/Jnw2BtJ2)

Comment: I love SFML! It would help a lot if you could contribute a [minimal, reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your question.

Comment: In fact, the simplest example of the program I've shared above is GIF. To make it a bit simpler: I would say that every second the value of the second element of the random named vector will decrease, then put it back into the second element, ie "replace" or "insert". So only the value of the second element will drop, but if you look at the GIF, the value of the first three decreases. My English is bad I don't think I can tell you more.

Comment: Sorry about my earlier comment btw, after a deeper analysis I realize that you indeed couldn't really make this shorter, and you also gave as much info as possible after selecting the most important part for the post. Good job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a hand.

Here's what's happening:

1. You create 5 numbers in the `random` array. You may not have noticed it, but they are numbered 0 to 4 (SFML is sitting on C++, and then it means that arrays starts at zero here).
2. Every second, you update the number stocked in the 3rd place of your `random` array.
3. Then it goes wrong: instead of updating the corresponding number in the `numbers` array, you cycle it with `push_back` and `erase`.

Understand me here: `push_back` create a new element at the end of the vector, while `erase` removes an element from the vector and then "sort out things" so there's not number gap in the index of the vector.

Effectively, you're handling `random` right, but when you try to update `number` you cycle through it. Like this:

```
seconds:       1 2 3 4 5 6


array content: 0 0 0 0 0 0
  (vertical)   1 1 1 1 1 1
               2 3 4 5 6 7
               3 4 5 6 7 8
               4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I'm not sure how clear I'm making this, but if you look at the array content, you'll see that by erasing and creating a new value at the end, you're cycling through the positions [2-4] of the array. That's why in your gif not all numbers are updated wrong, only 3 of them.

The obvious solutions would be to stop erasing and pushing back in the `numbers` array. You can update it the same way you updated the `random` array. It'll be fine.

Like this:

```
if (second == 1)
    {
    random.at(2)-=1;
    cout << random[2] << endl;
    numbers[2].setString(to_string(random[2]));
    clock.restart(); 
}
```

Have fun.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're very interested. You told me very well.(I may be writing something wrong because my English is bad.) But I don't know how to update. Can you give me a very brief example?

Comment: If you just want to update an existing item of the numbers array using the item from the random array which has the same index (I'll update the item at index 2 for the example, so you may want to adapt the code), you can do this: `numbers.at(2) = to_string(random[2]);`

Comment: "no operator" = "matches these operands
" but I will try. I thank you very much again.

Comment: I updated the answer with a code snippet. I hadn't noticed that `text` was from the SFML Text class. Way easier now that I have.

Comment: Thank you very much. You really solved this problem. I've been investigating for a long time. Thank you very much indeed.